# Defining default values with Firebase rules

Tags: angular, firebase

Is there a way to define default values directly in Firebase if a value is not provided in the payload?

For example, if I had a node that had as children: first_name, last_name, number_of_children, and date_modified, could only first_name, and last_name be required per firebase rules and could number_of_children just default to 0 if it's not included in the payload and could date_modified always be whatever the current server timestamp is?

Comment: Why don't you abstract that functionality into [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)?

Comment: Because I'm new to firebase and haven't discovered cloud functions yet.  Thanks I'll look into it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to set a default value for a node/property in security rules (nor in the SDK for that matter).

Firebase security can only affect *whether* data can be written (or read). It can't affect *what* data is written (or read).

The typical approach would be to either:

- code the default values into your app when you first write the node.
- code the default values into your app when you read a node that doesn't have a value.

You'll probably want to do a combination of both.